# ValueError: too many values to unpack: python list manipulation

Tags: python

I have a list in python

```
l= [[1105.46, 1105.75, 1105.75, 1105.46, 1051.46],
 [ 120.23,  120.23,  120.41,  20.41,  120.23]]
```

how can i get this one:

```
answer = [[1105.46,120.23], ....[1051.46,120.23]]
```

i did as:

```
answer = [[x, y] for x, y in l]
print answer
```

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Your `l` is a list of lists. So the `for x, y` is wrong. You want to `zip` both lists.

Comment: Do not do like that, just `answer = [list(tup) for tup in zip(*l)]` is sufficient to give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()` function from standard python:

```
l= [[1105.46, 1105.75, 1105.75, 1105.46, 1051.46],
 [ 120.23,  120.23,  120.41,  20.41,  120.23]]

new_list = []
for x, y in zip(l[0], l[1]):
    new_list.append([x, y])

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1105.46, 120.23], [1105.75, 120.23], [1105.75, 120.41], [1105.46, 20.41], [1051.46, 120.23]]
```

**One line version with list comprehension:**

```
print([[x, y] for x, y in zip(l[0], l[1])])
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one simple way:

```
>>> map(list, zip(*l))
[[1105.46, 120.23], [1105.75, 120.23], [1105.75, 120.41], [1105.46, 20.41], [1051.46, 120.23]]
```

If you don't care whether the nested elements are lists or tuples, it's even simpler:

```
>>> zip(*l)
[(1105.46, 120.23), (1105.75, 120.23), (1105.75, 120.41), (1105.46, 20.41), (1051.46, 120.23)]
```

Comment: your solution is more pythonic

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the below approach.

```
>>> l = [[1105.46, 1105.75, 1105.75, 1105.46, 1051.46], [ 120.23,  120.23,  120.41,  20.41,  120.23]]
>>>
>>> answer = [list(tup) for tup in zip(*l)]
>>>
>>> answer
[[1105.46, 120.23], [1105.75, 120.23], [1105.75, 120.41], [1105.46, 20.41], [1051.46, 120.23]]
>>>
```